# SCRIPT1007: Expected ']' error for eval expression while converting string to Array

Tags: javascript, java

I have been practicing ajax ,I have got following issue and the javascipt is failing at eval expression.I am using IE9 browser.It is giving error SCRIPT1007: Expected ']' at eval expression
The follwing is the javascript function and you can also find the problem that i have marked with arrows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callAjax(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET","ajax");
        xhr.send(null);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 ){
            if(xhr.status==200)
                var arrStr = xhr.responseText;

                //arrStr holds ['raj,'jay'] 
                ***var arr = eval(arrStr);------------->problem area***  
                var list ="";
                for (var i=arr; i<arr.length; i++){
                    list+=arr[i]+"<br>";
                }

                document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=list;
            } else if ( xhr.status==404) {
                document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML="<h6 style='color: red'>Invalid    Path</h6>"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You should be using `JSON.parse` rather than `eval`, which may give you a better error message. Either way, this looks like it's just a typo.

Comment: eval() is equally evil at all times. Your problem area is your `array` str that seems to be **NOT**  an `array`

Answer (score 0):

```
['raj,'jay']
```

You seem to be missing a closing quote after raj.

Answer (score 0):

If this `Array` string is given by user input or from another untrusted source, you should avoid `eval()` under all circumstances! (see what happens)

To store Arrays in strings, you should possibly take a look at [serialize](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and unserialize.